# How to fix Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId..."

Tags: java

I am following a question but I am getting this error. I am not sure how to fix it, I have looked up this error but i can't relate it to my code. Would appreciate it any help given!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {


    private static String name;
    private static String job;
    private static float salary;
    private static int id;

public Employee() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    name = scan.nextLine();
    job = scan.nextLine();
    salary = scan.nextFloat();
    id = scan.nextInt();
}
public Employee(String name, String job, float salary, int id) {
    name = name;
    job = job;
    salary = salary;
    id = id; 
}
public String getName(name) {
    return name;
}
public String getJobTitle(job) {
    return job;
}
public float salary(salary){
    return salary;
}
public static void showEmp() {
    System.out.println("Employee is called: " + name);
    System.out.println("They are a " +job); 
    System.out.println("Their salary is " + salary); 
    System.out.println("Their Employee ID number is " + id);
}
```

}

[image: This is the question]

Answer (score 0):

Your getter should not have a paramter:

```
 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

The variables should not be static also the showEmp method.
Full code should look like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String job;
    private float salary;
    private int id;

    public Employee() {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = scan.nextLine();
        job = scan.nextLine();
        salary = scan.nextFloat();
        id = scan.nextInt();
    }

    public Employee(String name, String job, float salary, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.job = job;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return job;
    }

    public float salary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void showEmp() {
        System.out.println("Employee is called: " + name);
        System.out.println("They are a " + job);
        System.out.println("Their salary is " + salary);
        System.out.println("Their Employee ID number is " + id);
    }
}
```